# iPod Touch Connected To WiFi But Bars Don’t Appear In Status Bar

Tags: ipod-touch, wifi

This only just started happening. Settings reports I am connected to the network, and I can browse the web in Safari, update apps, receive emails etc., but next to where it says "iPod" in the status bar, the little WiFi strength symbol is no longer displayed. Does anyone have an idea why, and how I can fix it?

Thanks, jrtc27

Answer (score 1):

Have you already turned off the iPod (by pressing the topmost button for several seconds)? The iPod asks you if you really want to turn off. Wait until ist is off, then switch it back on and see what happens with the status symbol.

Comment: That's helped me with several "oddities" on my Touch (mainly related to volume).

Comment: For some reason, even after holding the button down for 20 secs, the slide to power off slider wouldn't appear, so I killed it. That fixed it. Thanks